# How do i get a text object to change text dynamically?

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I would like to receive an object by its given name. Right now i have to get the object and set text like that:

```
stage.children[0].instance.instance.cta2.text = "SAMPLE TEXT";
```

I've found this method:

```
stage.getChildByName("cta2");
```

But it just works on the right nesting level - like this:

```
stage.children[0].instance.instance.getChildByName("cta2");
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution right?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking... Are you using Animate? Are you trying to refer to the text field by the "instance name" on its parent clip? Can you provide a little more info?